# Bluetooth: how to let ios attempt "App Not Installed"

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, bluetooth

I am doing something by Nordic nrf51822 BLE solution, is there any idea to let ios(iphone/ipad) attempt dedicated app is not installed after ble device pair to the iphone or ipad(like the attachment picture)? I search the internet and many forums, no found similar use case. But in Logitech bluetooth speaker, it has this function, my device is a BLE peripheral device, nordic has apple notification center service(ANCS) sample code, it seems only get the notifications from ios only, does any body know ANCS can do such function or not? And it's much appreciated if you have more information for me. thanks.

[App not installed picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0rvUhsrG_s3MnZSZzlUbWVGS2M&authuser=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alert you have shown is triggered when an MFi device is detected for which the app isn't installed.  MFi devices have an Apple 'chip' in them that presents an identity that iOS can use to identify the appropriate apps in the App Store.

BLE devices are [excluded from the MFi program](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2) and so you cannot present this alert when your BLE peripheral is discovered - indeed, without an app to discover the peripheral iOS won't even attempt to connect to the peripheral.